# Connecting GSM Dongle to Intel Galileo-Gen 2

Tags: serial, gsm, arduino-galileo

I have tried to connect a GSM dongle to a Intel Galileo Gen2 board and test the functionality of sending and receiving SMS through it.I know that it is easier to use a GSM shield to do above, but I'm currently doing a project in the way i mentioned above.Basically in Linux, we should know the serial port(like `ttyACM0` in `/dev` directory) correspond to the device to communicate with it(Using AT commands).

but when i tried it in Galileo board it doesn't show such a serial port.but it detect device because `lsusb` command shows the device.

does anyone can help me to solve this matter?

Comment: It may detect it as a USB device, but does it know what it is? Check `dmesg` when you plug it in, and also run `usb-devices` to see if it has a driver attached.

Comment: Many of these have to be kicked out of their initial mode of emulating a CD rom with windows drivers into a different mode which exposes USB-serial like devices.  There's a program called usbmodeswitch which sends the necessary SCSI commands.  **This is probably off topic for the arduino site.**

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the firmware. I'm not sure if this affects also ACM type serial ports, but the initial version of the firmware was not even creating standard /dev/ttySx, rather some weird proprietary interface.
Luckily this was fixed later on. So, in case you are still running the FW that the board came with, chances are you are having these weird serial ports.

Comment: In case my previous observation doesn't help, check the udev rules. It might simply miss the one for creating the appropriate type of character device.